# While executing oracle alter query getting error : ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-sql

I am trying to execute below query in my .sql file and getting error:

> quoted string not properly terminated

```
execute immediate 'alter tablespace '||tname||' add datafile '''||file_name||lname||ext||''' size '||add_space||'m autoextend off maxsize 30720m';
```

New code:

```
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 200
set head off;
set feedback off;
DECLARE
chr integer(12);
tname varchar (50):='${​​​i}​​​';  # Value I am getting from linux
file_name varchar (500);
add_space integer(10):=${​​​fiftin_per}​​​;
m_point varchar(200):=$mount_name;
var varchar(10):='/';
stamp varchar(50):='$random_val';
ext varchar:='.dbf'

BEGIN

file_name:=m_point||var||tname||stamp||ext;

dbms_output.put_line(file_name);  

#op : \oradata\data\test14_7_2021.dbf

dbms_output.put_line('alter tablespace '||tname||' add datafile '||file_name||' size '||add_space||'m autoextend off'); 

#op : alter tablespace test add datafile \oradata\data\test14_7_2021.dbf size 302m autoextend off

dbms_output.put_line('alter tablespace '||tname||' add datafile "'||file_name||'" size '||add_space||'m autoextend off');

#op :alter tablespace test add " datafile \oradata\data\test14_7_2021.dbf" size 302m autoextend off

dbms_output.put_line('alter tablespace '||tname||' add datafile '''||file_name||''' size '||add_space||'m autoextend off');

#op :alter tablespace test add datafile ' \oradata\data\test14_7_2021.dbf' size 302m autoextend off


END;
/
```

I have tried in three different ways to print that command and given output of the file as well please suggest.

Comment: You can use `dbms_output` to debug the generated statement. That line won't throw that error though, unless you somehow have a single quote embedded in one of the variables you're using to construct it; or if (as it doesn't have a semicolon) the following line continues the command and that has something extra/missing. The statement is invalid as you can't set `maxsize` with `autoextend off`, but [that isn't the error that generates](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e751e91657272d9c20948a59e8dd8cf).

Comment: do any of your variables have a single quote in them?

Comment: @AlexPoole : I have solved it by using dbms_output as you suggested but now the issue is I am passing the filename from linux to oracle query which is taking a space before the filename and while running the query I am getting invalid filename error.
I tried to pass the filename without quotes and it worked fine but with quotes its not working.
See below examples in my second comment:

Comment: @AlexPoole :
1. Without quotes :
`dbms_output.put_line( 'alter tablespace '||tname||' add datafile '||file_name||' size '||add_space||'m autoextend off');

OP : alter tablespace SYSAUX add datafile /oradata01/POCDB/data/SYSAUX112917893.dbf size 136m autoextend off`
2. Without quotes :
`dbms_output.put_line( 'alter tablespace '||tname||' add datafile '''||file_name||''' size '||add_space||'m autoextend off');

OP : alter tablespace SYSAUX add datafile ' oradata01/POCDB/data/SYSAUX112917893.dbf' size 136m autoextend off`
#Its adding a space after first quote which is not reuired.

Comment: @Jameson_uk : Yes, I declared one variable to print the single quotes after removing that the issue was solved but getting another issue now.

Comment: @Divya - [I am not seeing that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e40a1391248c11c7ed7a70c6905b790f). Possibly the mechanism you use to pass in the value is replacing the leading slash with a space somehow, but can't think why, or why it would be inconsistent. Are you sure you're actually passing exactly the same string in to both versions?

Comment: @AlexPoole : Its not replacing the slash with space. slash is also printed. Now I have declared same variables in oracle and tried to print file_name using dbmas_output, there its not printing any space but while passing file_name in alter command its printing the space. I'll am adding new code in question

Comment: The `$mount_name` has a space at the start; in the shell script you are presumably calling this from as a heredoc, add `echo <$mount_name>` and you'll be able to see it there too. If you can't fix it there you could `trim()` it in PL/SQL, but it seems like a shell issue really.

Comment: @AlexPoole : It seems the shell issue as `echo <$mount_name>` does not have any space . I used trim also but while passing the value in alter command that is not working either.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown your shell code. Without a [mcve] it's hard to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: @AlexPoole : I got the solution and updated the same here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue using below code:I trimmed the filename in linux and then passed that value into oracle:

```
var='/'
random_val=`date +"%d_%m_%y"_"%H"_"%M"_"%S"`
ex=".dbf";
fname="$mount_name$var${i}$random_val$ex"
ac=`echo -e "${fname}" | tr -d '[:space:]'`   # Trimmed filename
echo $ac
output3=`sqlplus -s usr/usr as sysbackup <<END2
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 200
set head off;
set feedback off;
DECLARE
tname varchar (50):='${i}';
file_name varchar (500):='$ac';
add_space integer(10):=${fiftin_per};

BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('alter tablespace '||tname||' add datafile '''||file_name||''' size '||add_space||'m autoextend off');
#op: alter tablespace test add datafile /oradata1/data/test12345.dbf size 1208m autoextend off;

dbms_output.put_line('We have added :'||file_name);
#op: We have added/oradata1/data/test12345.dbf 
END;
/
exit;
END2`
```